# Does Ansible Create A New SSH Connection For Each Copy Item?

Tags: ansible

I am copying files from one directory to another on a remote host.
A simplified example of what I am doing is:

```
tasks:
  - name: Find files
    find:
      paths: '/tmp/test/source/'
      patterns: ['*']
      recurse: true
      file_type: file
    register: find_result

  - name: Copy files
    copy:
      src: '/tmp/test/source'
      dest: '/tmp/test/destination'
      remote_src: yes
    with_items:
      - "{{ find_result.files }}"
```

There are 5 items in `/tmp/test/source` but when I run ansible with `-vvv` I get 37 instances of `ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible` in the log.

e.g. in this section it looks to be connecting 5 times before doing the copy

```
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> (0, b'/home/ansible\n', b'')
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/myuser.ssh/id_rsa_ansible"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/home/myuser.ansible/cp/efe18ae548 test.app.cloudapp.azure.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084="` echo /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> (0, b'ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084=/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084\n', b'')
Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/files/copy.py
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> PUT /home/myuser.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-95163adcnm_h2/tmpi76sdbpk TO /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084/AnsiballZ_copy.py
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/myuser.ssh/id_rsa_ansible"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/myuser.ansible/cp/efe18ae548 '[test.app.cloudapp.azure.com]'
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> (0, b'sftp> put /home/myuser.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-95163adcnm_h2/tmpi76sdbpk /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084/AnsiballZ_copy.py\n', b'')
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/myuser.ssh/id_rsa_ansible"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/home/myuser.ansible/cp/efe18ae548 test.app.cloudapp.azure.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084/ /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084/AnsiballZ_copy.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> (0, b'', b'')
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/myuser.ssh/id_rsa_ansible"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/home/myuser.ansible/cp/efe18ae548 -tt test.app.cloudapp.azure.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084/AnsiballZ_copy.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> (0, b'\r\n{"dest": "/tmp/test/destination/source", "src": "/tmp/test/source", "md5sum": null, "checksum": null, "changed": false, "uid": 1000, "gid": 1000, "owner": "ansible", "group": "ansible", "mode": "0775", "state": "directory", "size": 4096, "invocation": {"module_args": {"src": "/tmp/test/source", "dest": "/tmp/test/destination/source", "remote_src": true, "backup": false, "force": true, "follow": false, "_original_basename": null, "content": null, "validate": null, "directory_mode": null, "local_follow": null, "checksum": null, "mode": null, "owner": null, "group": null, "seuser": null, "serole": null, "selevel": null, "setype": null, "attributes": null, "regexp": null, "delimiter": null, "unsafe_writes": null}}}\r\n', b'Shared connection to test.app.cloudapp.azure.com closed.\r\n')
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/myuser.ssh/id_rsa_ansible"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/home/myuser.ansible/cp/efe18ae548 test.app.cloudapp.azure.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1622819470.8715484-187493017360084/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> (0, b'', b'')
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<test.app.cloudapp.azure.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/myuser.ssh/id_rsa_ansible"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/home/myuser.ansible/cp/efe18ae548 test.app.cloudapp.azure.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ansible && sleep 0'"'"''
ok: [test.app.cloudapp.azure.com] => (item={'path': '/tmp/test/source/5', 'mode': '0664', 'isdir': False, 'ischr': False, 'isblk': False, 'isreg': True, 'isfifo': False, 'islnk': False, 'issock': False, 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 1000, 'size': 0, 'inode': 1037548, 'dev': 2049, 'nlink': 1, 'atime': 1622819203.7465856, 'mtime': 1622818797.1473238, 'ctime': 1622818797.1473238, 'gr_name': 'ansible', 'pw_name': 'ansible', 'wusr': True, 'rusr': True, 'xusr': False, 'wgrp': True, 'rgrp': True, 'xgrp': False, 'woth': False, 'roth': True, 'xoth': False, 'isuid': False, 'isgid': False}) => {
"ansible_loop_var": "item",
"changed": false,
"checksum": null,
"dest": "/tmp/test/destination/source",
```

Is ansible creating a new ssh connection for every item in the `with_items`?

Comment: It will contact the target server over ssh several times for a single task and possibly for every items in that task. Meanwhile, unless you moved away from the default settings, ansible should re-use the same master ssh session avoiding most of the ssh handshake traffic after the first connection is done.